# Explaining large current spike in RC circuit for multisim simulation

Tags: relay, flyback

I am simulating the circuit shown in the figure below. In the simulation, switch S1 is repeatedly opened and closed at irregular intervals in short succession. The relay, K1 has a flyback diode attached for emf suppression from the relay coils. When R1 = 0, probe 1 measures massive currents up to 30A, despite there being a DC resistance of approximately 300 Ohm (in the relay coil). When R1 = 1 Ohm, the maximum current at the probe is approximately 15mA.

My question is, how is a 30A current possible through the probe if there is a large series DC resistance present? Is it due to some phenomena with the flyback diode, or is it maybe a bug with multisim? Why does the 1 Ohm resistor make such a large difference?

[image: Circuit Multisim Model]

Comment: You are shorting a capacitor - what currents would you expect?

Comment: The loop Probe1-C1-R1-S1 does **NOT** have a large series resistance when R1 = 0 ohm. The resistance of the relay coil is not in this loop so it cannot limit the current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When S1 is opened the capacitor charges through the relay.

When you close s1 you short out the capacitor leading to very high currents.

The one ohm resistor is in the capacitor switch path  and changes it from a dead short to a resistive path.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Simulation confirming the answers from RoyC and FakeMoustache. Probes indicate the current flow. The screenshot was taken directly after closing the switch.

Answer (score 0):

If either the cap or switch or both are is modelled ESR, the switch close operation shunts Vc/TotalESR=Ic

thus ESR=12V/30A

Answer (score 0):

$$ i=C \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{dt}},$$ and when you close the switch, you create a step function in the voltage across the capacitor.  The derivative of the step function has infinite height and zero width at the edge events, so you get a current spike.

The exact parameters of the spike, of course, will not be infinite height and zero width, but will be limited by any modeled internal resistances, thresholds, parasitic capacitances, etc.